# Is there a way to go to next occurrence without adding cursors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

To help me navigate I commonly make use of the ctrl+D shortcut for highlighting the next occurrence of a variable, then I click with my mouse to get out of multi-cursor mode and place a single cursor at the last highlighted occurrence.

But lately I'm working on minimizing mouse usage, so I need to avoid doing that last click. The problem is that I can't exit multi-cursor mode and stay on my last cursor. Pressing the `Esc` key teleports me back to the original occurrence, which is not what I want.

So:

- Is there a way to do something similar to ctrl+D but not open up multiple cursors?

  - Note: I know of a way but I think there are too many steps. 1) hit ctrl+D to highlight the word the cursor is currently on. 2) hit ctrl+F. 3) hit F3 to jump to next occurence
- If there's not a way to do the above, is there a way to exit multicursor mode but stay at the current occurrence rather than jump back to the original one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. The command is called "Find Next Selection" and defaults to `ctrl`+`f3`